# boost::asio how to pass member function to acceptor.async_accept()

Tags: c++, boost, handler

I am trying to pass a member function as an AcceptHandler to the async_accept() method of boost::asio. I get a compilation error saying:

> AcceptHandler type requirements not met

from the linked line:

> // If you get an error on the following line it means that your handler does not meet the documented type requirements for a AcceptHandler.

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload1.html) says the handler has to look like this:

```
void accept_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error) //documentation
{
  if (!error)
  {
    // Accept succeeded.
  }
}
```

my member function looks like this:

```
void WifiConnector::onAccept(const boost::system::error_code &ec) //my code
{
    if (ec) {
        std::cout << ec.message();
        return;
    }
    socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(mBuffer), &WifiConnector::readHandler);
}
```

I find no difference in that.

But I have to call the acceptor.async_accept() method like this:

```
acceptor.async_accept(socket, &WifiConnector::onAccept); //my code
```

instead of

```
acceptor.async_accept(socket, accept_handler); //documentation
```

because it is a member function I assume. If I try to just pass it like the documentation suggests:

```
acceptor.async_accept(socket, onAccept); //my code
```

there is an error saying: no instance of overloaded function.

**Is the error because I am passing the member function in the wrong way or what am I doing wrong?**

**Edit:**
I am calling the async_accept() method from within the object that holds the acceptor etc.

Comment: Where is the object for &WifiConnector::onAccept ? its not a static method.

Comment: it is created in the somewhere else and just gets a start-up call. All other method calls (such as `async_accept()` )are done within the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boost documentation mentions it explictly how to pass a non-static method to the acceptor [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AcceptHandler.html)

An excerpt from the above link:

```
void my_class::accept_handler(
    const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
  ...
}
...
acceptor.async_accept(...,
    boost::bind(&my_class::accept_handler,
      this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

You can replace `this` with the instance if your class.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the error because I am passing the member function in the wrong way or what am I doing wrong?

There is a difference in calling a plain function and calling (non-static) member function. The latter one can only be called together with a proper object. Therefore, you have to use one of the many ways to forward the call. The easiest approach is using a lambda:

```
WifiConnector wifi;
...
acceptor.async_accept(socket, [&wifi] (const auto& ec) { wifi.onAccept(ec); } );
```

Note however that you must make some serious thoughts about the lifetime of your wifi object, as other threads may access it now by reference and depend on that the owning thread keeps the object alive. For example passing `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr` objects rather than plain references (which may dangle) is not an uncommon practise inside asio callbacks.